# Magento Event dispach for Product View Page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer, url-rewrite

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. I want to write an observer on an event when the 'request path' is entered in the browser address bar. Can anyone please tell me which event dispatcher is called before url is re-written when the 'request path' (as present in CORE_URL_REWRITE) is entered in browser address bar.

Comment: do you want product view page event right?

Comment: yes @MeenakshiSundaramR

Comment: if i use this event(catalog_controller_product_init_before ) then it works only for target_path_url but not for request_path_url

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following event for product view page

```
controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view
```

Refer this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510293/add-events-for-before-after-a-action-of-a-controller-in-magento)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried this event , however when I type Target Path in browser address bar it works. However when I type request path I am unable to trap the event.

Comment: i tried with both target/request path. Its work fine for me.

Comment: actually We have our magento website (A) and another magento website (B). Requirement we have received is we do not wish to have product data in website A. What we are doing is we are doing API calls to fetch the data from website B. We are getting Product listing information correctly. When we navigate to product detail then in the browser url we see 'request path' from core_url_rewrite. However when we open this link we are getting 404 error. Please let us know if you need more information.

Comment: you can use same API call for get te product details in website B

Comment: but i want to show this product details on Website A which doesn't consist of any product details in data base it consist of only core_url_rewrites from website B so i want to just use Request_path_url from core_url_rewrites and call my website A custom observer so that from there i can make a call to a api request to website b and fetch product details and display it on my custom view page of Website A

Comment: @ Meenakshi Sundaram R do you have any idea how can we achieve this

Comment: @RupeshDeotale sorry i dont know :(